# what does four 8-32 holes on a 50mm bolt circle mean in this diagram? This drawing is for an ampflow E30-400-24 dc motor

Tags: technical-drawing

[image: what does four 8-32 holes on a 50mm bolt circle mean here?]

the link to the website is here:https://www.ampflow.com/motors/highPerformance/threeInch/

that drawing I think is the front of the motor, the shaft is in the center, the 4 holes around it are presumably threaded for mounting, but what diameter are those?

thank you in advance

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=8-32+bolt+size&ia=web

Comment: https://dcc.ligo.org/public/0027/T030118/001/T030118-01.pdf

Comment: *on a 50mm bolt center*.

Comment: 8/32" bolt hole.

Comment: Some background reading on the [Unified Thread Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Thread_Standard). 8-32 means a #8 thread with 32 threads per inch. The table in the link lists drill sizes for tapping.  Bolt circle - the centers of the holes are on a 50 mm diameter circle.

Comment: @r13 8-32 doesn't mean 8/32" = 1/4" = 0.25" Wikipedia suggests 0.136" for a 8-32 UNC tap.

Answer (score 5):

The diameter of those four holes is specified by the designator "8-32" which means *standard screw diameter #8, threaded to 32 threads per inch*. This is the usual way threaded holes are called out, rather than by saying the actual hole diameter in decimal inches and then saying the thread pitch.

So the machinist who has to make the part knows what drill bit diameter to use to make a hole and then tap it to 8-32 by looking it up on a chart, and the engineer who wants to buy the part knows exactly what mounting screws to use to attach it to another machine part.